# Ensemble network with categorical distribution in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, distribution, ensemble-learning, tensorflow-probability

I have `n` networks, each with the same input / output. I want to randomly select one of the outputs according to a categorical distribution. [Tfp.Categorical](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/Categorical) outputs only integers and I tried to do something like

```
act_dist = tfp.distributions.Categorical(logits=act_logits) # act_logits are all the same, so the distribution is uniform
rand_out = act_dist.sample()
x = nn_out1 * tf.cast(rand_out == 0., dtype=tf.float32) + ... # for all my n networks
```

But `rand_out == 0.` is always false, as well as the other conditions.

Any idea for achieving what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also look at MixtureSameFamily, which does a gather under the covers for you.

```
nn_out1 = tf.expand_dims(nn_out1, axis=2)
...
outs = tf.concat([nn_out1, nn_nout2, ...], axis=2)
probs = tf.tile(tf.reduce_mean(tf.ones_like(nn_out1), axis=1, keepdims=True) / n, [1, n]) # trick to have ones of shape [None,1]
dist = tfp.distributions.MixtureSameFamily(
        mixture_distribution=tfp.distributions.Categorical(probs=probs),
        components_distribution=tfp.distributions.Deterministic(loc=outs))
x = dist.sample()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know this class and it is exactly what I needed. I edited your answer with the code I wrote using `MixtureSameFamily.` 
One question though. If the probabilities are a function of the same input of the components and I want to train it, it seems I can't. I have read that in TF the gradient does not backpropagate through integers, and for instance it doesn't through `one_hot` and `gather`. Since `Categorical` output are integers, may this be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use tf.equal, because Tensor == 0 is always False.

Separately though, you might want to use OneHotCategorical. For training, you might also try using RelaxedOneHotCategorical.

Comment: Yes, I know why it is false. I am looking for a way to tell it to compare to the output of the `output` function, not to the function itself.
What's the benefit of using OneHotCategorical? I never head of it, and from the description is seems basically the same for my purpose.